# getting an undefined method error from "_user.html.erb" in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

If I am getting this error

`undefined method impressionist_count' for nil:NilClass` after trying to use this line inside _user.html.erb

```
<%= @user.impressionist_count+@user.microposts.sum(&:impressionist_count) %>
```

where does it need to be defined? I already have this inside user.rb

```
def impressionist_count
    impressions.size
  end
```

I tried it in various helpers but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "render @users" each user is accessible to the partial as the local variable "user". Your partial should look like:

```
<%= user.impressionist_count+user.microposts.sum(&:impressionist_count) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is defined, but the `@user` object is not. This should've been assigned in the controller in order for it to work inside your view, or your partial should've been provided an object when you're rendering it.

Maybe you have something like:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'user') %>
```

What you might need is this if you have a `user` variable:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'user', :object => user) %>
```

Errors including the phrasing "`for nil`" are an indication of an undefined value being used incorrectly.

Comment: This is what I have in users\index.html.erb (`<%= render @users %>`). Inside the index function of the user controller, I tried to put in `@user = User.find(params[:id])`, but I'm now getting Couldn't find User without an ID

Comment: What is `@users` defined as? Don't forget that `index` does not get an `:id` parameter.

Comment: this is @users inside the index: `@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page]).all`

Comment: Index actions are used for listing "all" of a model, eg. `User.all`. This produces a collection of objects which must be iterated, rendering each object individually (this is why `@user` is singular inside the partial).

Comment: depending on your version of ruby on rails, @users will do a collection-of-partials render, just shorthand.